# How can i turn this into generic expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, linq-expressions

I want to make this linq into generic expression tree.

```
_context.Set<TEntity>().Where<TEntity>(List => !_list.Any(list1 => List1.Id == list.Id))
```

basically my issue is, i have a generic class, and i want to pass on list, and a Dbcontext, and from that i want to check if any of the values from the list exists in the DbContext.Table1, if they do then add them, if not then delete them..

I tried passing in the `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> match` as the where clause but i am getting this error when i try to execute this inside the generic class, but when I do it in my main class and explicitly define class it works..

this linq works outside of the generic class
    _context.table1.Select(table => !list.Any(table1 => table1.Id == table.Id));

when i run it in the generic class like `_context.Set<TEntity>().Where(match)` where match is `table => !list.Any(table1 => table1.Id == table.Id` I get this error

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

So, I think i want to create a Expression inside my generic class Am i going about it the right way?

Comment: Have you tried doing something like var listIds = list.Select(l=>l.Id); and then have match be table => !listIds.Contains(table.Id) ?

Comment: What is the relation between `List`, `_list`, `list1`, `List1` and `list`? I would strongly urge you to use better variable names and also post code that actually works.